# OAuth1Session.fetch_request_token

Tags: api, user-interface, oauth, python-3.4, cx-freeze

Firstly I am very much learning to code, so I apologies if this turns out to be something extremely silly on my end.

I am trying to implement a small app to obtain keys from the Etsy site using python, and to implement a tkinter GUI, however, when I compile this using cx_Freeze into a windows exe it fails to work. (Note it works in python IDE window no problem)

I have narrowed the problem to a function making the initial request for keys, and obtaining at the fetch_reponse stage is someone able to provide some guidance on what might cause this to fail once it is has been frozen in an exe?

```
    def apiPerms_key_submission():
        '''GUI Function that calls problem code'''

        key_request() # submits API request.
        mb.showinfo("Etsy API - Key Request", "Obtaining API Keys")
        perm_win.destroy()
        wb.open(keysDict['loginURL'])
        verify_token_entry()

    def key_request():
        '''
        '''
        trg_url = perm_url_req(selection)
        clientKey = keysDict['clientKey']
        clientSecret = keysDict['clientSecret']

        #Assign secret and key to parameter.
        auth_req = OAuth1Session(clientKey, client_secret=clientSecret)
        #Makes call to url for api provider.
        fetch_response = auth_req.fetch_request_token(trg_url)

        # Extract tokens and url to confirm account.
        oauth_token = fetch_response.get('oauth_token')
        oauth_token_secret = fetch_response.get('oauth_token_secret')
        login_url = fetch_response.get('login_url')

        keysDict['toauth_token'] = oauth_token
        keysDict['toauth_token_secret'] = oauth_token_secret
        keysDict['loginURL'] = login_url
```

Setup.py
        import sys
        from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

```
    opts = {'includes':['requests_oauthlib', 'requests', 'urllib.parse', 
    'json', 'os'],\
    'include_files':['Etsy_API_GUI_v1.py','Etsy_OAuth_v1.py',\
                     'Application 
    Icon.ico','Etsy_API_Token_Req_Dev_Diary_v1.txt']}

    base = None
    if sys.platform == 'win32': base= 'WIN32GUI'

    setup (name='Etsy API OAuth Handshake',
          version = '1.0',
          description="Etsy API OAuth Handshake",
          author='Gavin White',
          options = {'build_exe':opts},
          executables = [Executable('Etsy_API_GUI_v1.py',\
                             icon='Application Icon.ico',\
                             shortcutName='Etsy API Key', base=base)])
```

If you need the whole code base I can provide, but seemed superfluous. I also don't get any errors when I run before freezing into a windows exe.

Thank you for any help that you might be able to provide in advanced.

Comment: You'll need to provide your setup.py that you used to build your frozen executable and the output that you got demonstrating the error you are receiving.

Comment: I have now included my setup.py file contents - any help on this is really appreciated.